# Refer to base types that have a raw type constraint

Tags: generics, scala, hadoop, mapreduce, type-inference

I've been playing around with Scala, trying to get [SMR](https://github.com/dlwh/smr/) to compile in Scala IDE with 2.9.1.  SMR seems to have gone untouched since 2008-ish, and there are a lot of unresolved compile errors.  The one that I am getting stuck on is this line:

```
jobConf.setMapRunnerClass(classOf[ClosureMapper[_,_,_,_]]);
```

ClosureMapper is defined thus:

```
class ClosureMapper[K1,V1,K2,V2] extends MapRunnable[Writable,Writable,Writable,Writable] { 
  ...
}
```

and the error I get is:

```
type mismatch; 
found : java.lang.Class[smr.hadoop.ClosureMapper[_, _, _, _]](classOf[smr.hadoop.ClosureMapper]) 
required: java.lang.Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunnable]
```

So it looks to me like the JobConf class's setMapRunnerClass method is constraining the type parameter to inherit from MapRunnable (which ClosureMapper does), but more specifically MapRunnable's *raw* type, which Scala doesn't seem to appreciate.

I have tried the following, but got a different error:

```
jobConf.setMapRunnerClass(classOf[ClosureMapper]);
```

That one gives `class ClosureMapper takes type parameters`

Any ideas on how to get Scala to recognize the raw type constraint?

Answer (score 0):

You might have to specify a bound for the type parameters of `ClosureMapper`:

```
jobConf.setMapRunnerClass(classOf[ClosureMapper[_ <: ClosureMapper[_],_ <: ClosureMapper[_],_ <: ClosureMapper[_],_ <: ClosureMapper[_]]]);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to do it.  For one, the 4 type arguments to ClosureMapper are constrained to Writable, not ClosureMapper.  Secondly, even if I specify classOf[ClosureMapper[Writable,Writable,Writable,Writable]], it doesn't work because for some reason it cannot infer that the (fully specified) ClosureMapper class isn't also a *raw* MapRunnable.